# Past Perfect Tense

Tags: standard-german

When should one use the past perfect? ("war... ge-[verb]t/en") I understand that the simple past is (roughly) for stories and the present perfect is (roughly) for the typical-past tense. (Feel free to correct me if either of these sound wrong.) Any help you could provide on this front would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty much the same case as with English grammar. I don't get your question?

Answer (score 7):

The tense *Plusquamperfekt* is for the tense *Präteritum* what the tense *Perfekt* is for the tense *Präsens*.

You have to understand *Präteritum* isn't related to the past at all ¹). It's related to a time a story plays in. Which is often the past, but it may be also the future or "fantasy time" in an alternate reality. You can also see *Präteritum* in this *Erzählzeit* describes present and future events, as *Präsens* does it for reality.

> Das Planet-Express-Raumschiff **hob** kurz ab und **stürzte** dann zurück in den Hangar.
>
> *Später* **stellte** sich heraus, dass Bender die L-Einheit **verbogen hatte**.

---

¹) if not used as a replacement for *Perfekt* with some common verbs.

Comment: +1 for Futurama reference.

Comment: I am not sure whether "Präteritum isn't related to the past at all" isn't exaggerating the point a bit. The literal translation of the latin word "Präteritum" is "What has gone by"...

Comment: Yeah. It's a misnomer. It describes a fantasy world and I'm pretty sure there was SF even in ancient Rome.